# Why can't $\partial X^i/\partial x^j$ be the components of a tensor field?

Tags: differential-geometry, multilinear-algebra

From *Paul Renteln, "Manifolds, Tensors and Forms"* in a chapter on tensor fields:

> **Exercise 3.22** Not every object with indices is a tensor field. Let $X = X^i \partial / \partial x^i$ be a vector field. Show that the functions $\partial X^i/\partial x^j$ cannot be the components of any tensor field, by showing that they do not obey the transformation law for tensor field components.

I don't see why the given functions should not define a tensor field... the vector field $X$ and the coordinate functions $x^i$ are given, so $\partial X^i/\partial x^j$ are smooth functions for every $(i, j)$.

What wrong with letting $$T^{ij} := \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}$$ and $$T := T^{ij}\  e_i \otimes e_j = \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^j}\ e_i \otimes e_j$$ for some basis $\{e_i\}$? The components $T^{ij}$ are smoothly varying functions, so by definition $T$ should be a tensor field... ?

Comment: Where do you verify the definition? You seem to be using the definition involving a certain behaviour under coordinate transformations. You need to check this.

Comment: @Thomas: by definition, "a tensor field ... is a map from $M$ to $T^r_s$ such that, on any coordinate patch, the components are smoothly varying functions". Since, in the exercise, the components come from a vector field and there is only a single coordinate patch, I think they are smooth?

Comment: No. You should review the definition. For a tensor, a coordinate change has to obey a certain transformation rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you defined is a perfectly good tensor field.  The exercise in the book is a little misleading.  I think what the author really intended to say was something like this:

> Let $X$ be a vector field.  Show that there is no tensor field $T$ whose coefficients in every local coordinate chart $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ are of the form $T^{ij} = \partial X^i/\partial x^j$.